# Sort Result array by an Array with keys

Tags: php

I have 2 Arrays:

(1) Array with Key => Value, and Array (2) with no relevant Keys and as Values the keys from array 1 in different order. Is there an elegant solution to put array 1 in the same order like the values in array two?

```
$data = array(
'NAME' => 'XYZ',
'NUMB' => 1234,
'CITY' => 'TEST'
);

$sort = array(
'A1' => 'CITY',
'XY' =>  'NUMB',
'XX' => 'NAME',
);

$result = array(
'CITY' => 'TEST,
'NUMB' => 1234,
'NAME' => 'XYZ',
);
```

Comment: Not really seeing the logic here, particularly for `'NUMB' => 1234`.

Comment: in array 2, 1234 if not a key in array 1.

Comment: is that a mistake in writing question ? I mean 1234 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    'NAME' => 'XYZ',
    'NUMB' => 1234,
    'CITY' => 'TEST'
);

$sort = array(
    'A1' => 'CITY',
    'XY' => 'NUMB',
    'XX' => 'NAME'
);

$result = array();
foreach($sort as $key => $value){
    if(isset($data[$value]))
        $result[$value] = $data[$value];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: as you didn't mention anything about 1234, I am expecting that a mistake in writing question.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the typo, and think you want this:

```
$result=array();
foreach ($sort as $var=>$val){
    $result[$val]=$data[$val];
}
```